# python find column size of 2D list passed in as argument

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I'm trying to write a function to compute the dot product of two 2D lists passed in as arguments, lets call them `x` and `y`.

My idea is to first create a 2D list of zeros of the proper dimensions for the result of the dot product. In order to do so, I need to find the column size of `y` when computing `x * y`

```
dim1 = len(x)
dim2 = len(y[0])
result = [0]*dim1*dim2
```

The above code was my idea for getting these dimensions, however it fails on the second line due to an error:

`dim2 = len(y[0])`

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

My python interpreter seems to not like that I am assuming my arguments will be 2D lists. It seems to think it'll be a 1D list. How can I get the column length of the 2D list. I am assuming the 2D lists passed in will be of dimensions `NxM`, so it should be a clean rectangle shape list/matrix.

I am not able to use numpy for this case.

Comment: what is your input y?

Comment: Not sure what you mean 2D list.  The dot product between two 2D vectors would look like:  (x0, y0) dot (x1, y1) == x0*x1 + y0*y1.  A single value.  Please include the example data x and y, then we can help better.

Comment: _I am not able to use numpy for this case._ Why? Is it something we might be able to help with?

Comment: _My python interpreter seems to not like that I am assuming my arguments will be 2D lists. It seems to think it’ll be a 1D list._ If you’re getting that error when you run the program then Python isn’t assuming, it’s stating.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].